# Gradle: Modifying contents of a property file inside a jar file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

There a is config.properties file in the project.jar file.
I need to modify one of the property in this file without extracting the jar file. How to do this and is it safe to do this ,since we are modifying Jar?

Code I tried is:

```
def configProperties = new Properties()
def configPropFile = projectJar + '/config.properties'
configProperties.load(configPropFile)
configProperties.setProperty('versions', '1.7)
configProperties.store(configPropFile.newWriter(), null)
```

This gives me exception:

```
Execution failed for task 'changeProp'.
> No signature of method: java.util.Properties.load() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [/com/codebase/project/config.properties]
  Possible solutions: load(java.io.InputStream), load(java.io.Reader), clear(), clone(), sort(), find()
```

Also tried:

```
configProperties.load(ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(configPropFile))
```

This gives me exception:

```
> Ambiguous method overloading for method java.util.Properties#load.
  Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
        [class java.io.InputStream]
        [class java.io.Reader]
```

I am new to gradle, Can some one help me with this?

Comment: You mean to change the properties file within the jar so that the jar is changed afterwards? The easiest way is to unpack / change / repack.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: I am having the same problem trying to read from a properties file.